# share unix socket from docker container to ubuntu host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, puma

Hello I am trying to share a unix socket from my docker container rails app to my ubuntu host in order to connect puma server with nginx reverse proxy.

In my docker-compose file I have:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  web:
    command: puma -b 'unix:///var/run/puma.sock?umask=0777'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/puma.sock:/var/run/puma.sock:rw
```

I am getting this error on web service when loading with volumes:

```
web_1       | * Listening on unix:///var/run/puma.sock?umask=0777
web_1       | /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:359:in `unlink': Is a directory @ unlink_internal - /var/run/puma.sock (Errno::EISDIR)
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:359:in `rescue in add_unix_listener'
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:356:in `add_unix_listener'
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:141:in `block in parse'
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `each'
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `parse'
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:144:in `load_and_bind'
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/single.rb:87:in `run'
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:174:in `run'
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:77:in `run'
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.9.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/bin/puma:23:in `load'
web_1       |   from /usr/local/bundle/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
```

I am expecting this behavior:

```
web_1    | Puma starting in single mode...
web_1    | * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.3.7-p456), codename: Private Caller
web_1    | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
web_1    | * Environment: production
web_1    | I, [2018-12-08T15:10:17.371560 #1]  INFO -- sentry: ** [Raven] Raven 2.7.4 ready to catch errors
web_1    | I, [2018-12-08T15:10:17.686838 #1]  INFO -- : Raven 2.7.4 ready to catch errors
web_1    | * Listening on unix:///var/run/puma.sock?umask=0777
web_1    | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Error only occurs when I use volumes. can you give me a hand?

Comment: If you use a TCP socket instead, you're in a situation Docker handles much more straightforwardly.

Comment: I have tried with TCP socket but can not connect puma with nginx for some weird reason, Browsing thru web I found many tutorials to connect puma with nginx but almost all had unix socket connection

Comment: @CarlosGómez, You cannot (or, should not) safely connect to a Unix socket across kernel boundaries. The unix socket is a file handle and the kernel manages it's data and state as required. Docker and the host don't share the unix socket's state. See, for example [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/124517/whats-the-difference-between-unix-socket-and-tcp-ip-socket).

Comment: @Myst I see, at last I decide to use TCP as DavidMaze says, thanks for the explanation.